# The cylinder does not embed into $\Bbb C^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

The cylinder $\Bbb R\times S^1$ can be viewed as a complex manifold with a flat metric by viewing it has the quotient $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, where $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R=\Bbb C$. (In fact it makes the cylinder into a Kähler manifold.)

> **Problem:** Show that there is no isometric holomorphic embedding
>   $$\varphi:\Bbb R\times S^1\hookrightarrow \Bbb C^n,$$
>   for any $n$, where $\Bbb C^n$ has the standard Kähler structure.

**Motivation:** I was trying to answer another of my questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737794/embedding-of-k%C3%A4hler-manifolds-into-bbb-cn), and after some research I found [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/78670) mathoverflow post of Peter Kronheimer claiming the above. He gives the following reason.

> **Hint:** Apply the maximum modulus principle to the derivative of $\varphi$.

I tried this approach without any success. Does anybody know how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? If $\phi$ is an isometric holomorphic embedding $\Bbb C/\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow\Bbb C^n$, it lifts to a $\Bbb Z$-invariant holomorphic map $\tilde\phi\colon\Bbb C\to\Bbb C^n$ pulling back the standard Kähler form on $\Bbb C^n$ to the standard Kähler form on $\Bbb C$, i.e.,
$$\tilde\phi^*\left(\sum_{j=1}^n dz^j\wedge d\bar z^j\right) = dz\wedge d\bar z.$$
This means that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \big|(\tilde\phi{}^j)'(z)\big|^2 = 1$ for all $z$. Applying Liouville's Theorem to $(\tilde\phi{}^j)'$, we infer that all $(\tilde\phi{}^j)'$ must be constant. But each $\tilde\phi{}^j$ is also $\Bbb Z$-invariant, so the only constant that can work is $0$. Oops.